# Open VSCode from Remotly Server to Local like WSL2

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, server, windows-subsystem-for-linux, remote-server

Recently i created one server (with centos) on another computer, i assigned static local ip (192.168.1.100) and i my computer has local static ip too (192.168.1.50), and i would like open the vscode from my local computer when i run "code" command on remote server (like code .) inside vscode of my computer.

Basically like WSL2 works, but, when we install the distro of WSL2, the vscode install automatically one extension for WSL2, and that works.

And another question, is about the terminal of local vscode, when i open the vscode terminal, i would like to open the remote server terminal (ssh) on the current folder. (Exactly like WSL2)

Basically i would like create a WSL2 outside from the same computer. The "SubSystem" i want to install  are on another computer (my server)

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you're looking for [1](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/190)

A simpler method would be to install ssh-remote plugin in VSCode and you will see Remote Explorer in your left bar. After you log in once to that server you will see the connection and with a simple click, you can connect from there.